# iOS: Can I register for a textfieldDidBeginEditing from a table view?

Tags: ios, notifications

I have a complex problem, I'm solving more and more :-) I have an embedded tableview. If the table changes to edit mode and some textfields at the bottom of the screen should be edited, they are hidden behind the keyboard.

I'v subclassed now UITableView and got it to work with these notifications:

```
- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

}
```

But now, if a user edits a textfield and then jumps to another textfield I want my functions again to calculate if the offset can be reset or not. However these notifications are only triggered when the keyboard shows or gets hidden. So how can I register for a textfield begins editing? Of course I have the delegate methods (and I use them in the respective view controller), but I don't see where these two things connect? I cannot register for them in the table view (well it just doesn't work..) and it doesn't make sense to put all my code for the table view in my viewcontroller...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already subclassed `UITableView`, so add some more methods that your view controller can use to pass along the message.

```
// CustomTableView.h
@interface CustomTableView : UITableView

- (void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
```

Or you could do something that doesn't look like the UITextFieldDelegate methods at all:

```
- (void) updateOffsetsToShowRect:(CGRect)rect;
```

Then in your view controller's implementation of `textFieldDidBeginEditing:`, you can call those methods on your custom table view.

Comment: I thought about that...but do I need to register my tableview as well as my viewcontroller as delegate of the textfields and then both textFieldDidBeginEditing methods are triggered?

Comment: @MichiZH you can't register two delegates. You have to call the table view's methods manually.